# Symfony 5 TreeBuilder compatibility

Tags: php, symfony

I have a symfony bundle working on Symfony 3 and 4. But Since Symfony 5, the method define configuration inside TreeBuilder has changed: [Deprecated tree builders without root nodes](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-2-important-deprecations#deprecated-tree-builders-without-root-nodes).

From  this

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->get('bundle_name');
```

To this

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('bundle_name');
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->getRootNode();
```

Since I want my bundle to work from Symfony 3 and Symfony 5, how can I change the TreeBuilder to work in all the cases?

Comment: I have not tested this out, but [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/27476#issuecomment-457910730) seems promising: `$rootNode = method_exists(TreeBuilder::class, 'getRootNode') ? $treeBuilder->getRootNode() : $treeBuilder->get('bundle_name');`. Use `getRootNode` if it exists, otherwise do as you did before.